# Origin of word pronoun

Tags: meaning

Recall preposition. For example of preposition, there are "on", "in" and "about" etc. Note that they has a front position of noun, e.g. in bag, about book.

So pre means front. For instance, by considering word "previous", whose meaning is front of fixed time, we can know that pre means front.

I have a question about word pronoun. Here by considering him, he, and you etc, we know that pro means instead of. So I want to know the well-known word like the above case containing pro whose meaning is instead of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, the only Latin loanword besides *pronoun* where the prefix means ’instead of, on behalf of‘ is [*proconsul*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proconsul), a Roman official who acted on a consul's behalf. The prefix in words like *provide/provision* or *proceed* takes the meaning 'before, in front of' in either time, *pro-videre* = 'see forward,' i.e., make provision for, or space, *pro-cedere* = 'move forward.' This movement away, whether real or metaphorical, is why the preposition *pro* took the ablative case in Latin.

An official serving pro tem[pore] serves on behalf of another, such as the president pro tempore of the US Senate serving on behalf of the president of the Senate, the vice president, but the phrase means 'for the time [being].'